# comparison between nullptr and boolean

Tags: c++, nullptr

While I was experimenting with null pointers, I tried to write a code to check whether a pointer was null or not:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;
int main(){
    int *p = 0;
    if(!p == true){
        cout<<"nullptr\n";
    }
    else{
        cout<< "no\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

which worked fine without any error but when I tried this (which according to me was basically the same thing but is clearly not):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;
int main(){
    int *p = 0;
    if(p == false){
        cout<<"nullptr\n";
    }
    else{
        cout<< "no\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I got an error: "error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and 
integer [-fpermissive]"

---

Can anyone tell me how are these two codes different and why am I getting an error in the second code?

Comment: `!p` is a bool.  `p` is an `int*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with the difference between *implicit* and *explicit* conversions, and the special status of the `bool` type with respect to explicit conversions.

Generally, while you can convert between integers and pointers (either direction), you can only do it *explicitly* with a cast.  No cast means no conversion and you get an error.

The special exception here comes from the special treatment of the `bool` type and the special status of "boolean contexts".  Basically, there are a few syntactic contexts:

- the conditional expression operand of an `if`, `while` or `for` statement
- the operand of a `!` unary operator
- the first operand of a `?`/`:` ternary operator
- the operands of `&&`/`||`

which are "boolean contexts" -- the operand must be a bool value -- and where operands of other types may be implicitly converted to `bool` **even if such conversions normally require an explicit cast**

That shows why your first example works -- you're using a unary `!` which is one of those special boolean contexts which allows conversion to bool as if there was an explicit cast present.

This is nothing in particular to do with pointers -- the same thing happens with any user defined (class) type that has an `explicit operator bool` conversion defined for it.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `!` on the pointer `p`, you get a `true` or a `false` value depending on whether `p` is `nullptr` or not. Obviously, comparing 2 `bool`s is fine.

When you do `p == true`, the left hand side is still a pointer, and you cannot compare pointers and `bool`s.